How to disable nearby device on my phone (for privacy reasons)?
I'm using Infinix Note 30 with Android 13. I'm currently trying to achieve location privacy on my phone. I have denied location permission for all apps (except system apps and Google Play Services, because I cannot disable it, it says device need permission to operate), I also disabled all "location services" because I figure these location services are collecting my location data.
I only enable these services when I desperately need the GPS and disable them when I no longer need (the GPS is really bad without these location services, maybe it was intentional to punish user for disabling them by not adding necessary GPS feature to base android?).
Then I realized apps still can track my location through "nearby device" feature in two ways:

By scanning for nearby device on my phone
By scanning for nearby device on other phone near me and figure out my approximate location if my phone was detected on that other phone

Fixing 1 is easy, I simply deny nearby device permissions for all apps (except system apps, because I cannot disable it, it says device need permission to operate). I also disabled "Bluetooth scanning" to stop apps and services from scanning for nearby devices.
Fixing 2 on the other hand, I cant find the option to disable nearby device feature. I only can deny nearby device permission for app in my phone, but I can't find the settings to disable nearby device feature to prevent other phone from scanning my phone.
Does anyone know where is the settings to disable nearby device feature?
Denying nearby device permission is not enough, I need to disable the nearby device feature itself.

See this. Is your device rooted? If so, NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES can be disabled using app ops using PermissionManagerX

If your device isn't rooted you can give this app elevated privileges to run adb (see adb access in menu and in help) //Usually ADB is enough to change manifest permissions. Except if the device is very restricted.//You can test and report

@beeshyams is that safe ? i dont want to brick my phone just because of this matter. And also, privacy is protected by law, so there must be a way to disable it without hacking my own phone like that right ?

Please don't a) bring legal issues to the table. What is legal in one country may not be in another. Besides, this site or users are not lawyers give legal advice b) use terms like hacking loosely without defining it as per your understanding. You asked how do it from a privacy perspective and you got one way. Use it or don't, it's your choice. You can ask in your phone forums for alternative ways if they exist

Absolutely safe to use this app. It is developed by a valued contributor to this site and won't brick your phone unless you mess with system apps permissions

@beeshyams oh come on, dont be rude like that, i dont meant hacking in exact meaning, it is just a metaphor for doing something in unintended or hacky way (hence the term hacking). Surely that if it is intended for phone user to be able to disable nearby device feature, the settings would be available through built-in settings app instead of needing to  ̶h̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶h̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶t̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ modify the phone settings in unintended way by giving adb elevated privilages which came with various security risk from doing that?

@beeshyams anyway thanks for confirming it is safe. But im not tech savvy enough to actually do that because i dont even know what adb is nor do i know how to use it. Im still looking for safer way to do it.

Android doesn't permit users to calibrate permissions beyond a point and that's why you need to other ways (what you call hacky) // whether you want to go down that path is of course your choice. Should you decide to, this information aboutadb will be a great starting point (Hint:On most tags on this site, if you click the tag and then learn more you have a good summary) //All the best with your search to do it in a safer way - not to discourage you but a diligent search will tell you why it's not possible

Knowing about permissions is a good starting point for you to make the search meaningful and once you do that see the first comment of mine and the link therein

giving adb elevated privilages which came with various security risk from doing that? is a valid concern and you can ask that as a separate question here, if need be linking this question for context
